# Deliver specific delivered activities(deliver.xxxx) from developer stream to Integration stream

Tags: clearcase

I am getting following error post delivery:

We have 2 clearcase servers remote and local once code is delivered to remote SDS for the effect to take place in localclear case we manually execute `ct deliver -complete` but I am getting below errors .

Errors

```
user@s007246a ~]$ tailf xxx_sds.deliver.log
activity:deliver.1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
activity:deliver.2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222"
activity:deliver.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333"
activity:deliver.4444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444"
cleartool: **Error: Unable to read change set entry for activity** "33333333333333333333333".
**cleartool: Error: Unable to convert diffs to elements.
cleartool: Error: Unexpected error in deliver.
cleartool: Error: Unable to perform merge.
cleartool: Error: Unable to do integration.
cleartool: Error: Unable to deliver stream "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".**
```

Error 2.
ct: Warning: A version in the change set of activity "deliver.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" is currently unavailable.

Query:

1. can we deliver a particular deliver.xxxxxxx activity from designer stream to integration stream if yes how ??
2. If above query is achievable can we also deliver some activities say deliver.1111111 deliver.222222222 deliver.33333333 out of deliver.nnnnnnnnn activities from SDS to Integration stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Independently of your queries, you must solve first the error message you get on the complete step of your deliver.

See "[Unable to deliver stream is returned when completing a UCM Posted deliver](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21268613)"

> Cause
>
> - The Project VOB may be in sync but the Component VOB(s) at the source and target sites may not be in sync.
> - The target stream is locked. This can be checked by looking at the properties of the target stream.